# Racing java.util.Collections.sort

Tags: java, mergesort, timsort

I found a more efficient sort algorithm with average and best performance of O(N), and worst performance of O(N Log(N)). On **uniformly distributed data**.

I need your help to tell me if my tests is correct, and my biggest question is: How can I test it on real world data?

This question going to have five parts:

- Short brief about java.util.Collections.sort
- Explanation about my algorithm
- Testing outputs
- Source code of my algorithm
- Source code of my testing program

### Short brief about java.util.Collections.sort

Java use modefied [merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mergesort/info) algorithm in [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) implementation. From jdk 7 it been [replaced](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/bfd7abda8f79) with [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). In my tests I been working on jdk 6. Same as used in Android.

### Explanation about my algorithm

I found an interesting approach for sorting. I use statistic sort. Or to be more exact linear statistic sort. I assume that all the variables have "good" [Linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). So I am calculating the approximated index of a variable based on its value. If more than one variable have the same index, I place it in buffer array. Than I sort the buffer using Collections.sort(). The idea is that the buffer will be very small so sorting it will be ~O(1). This is the difference between performance of O(N) and O(N Log(N)), in worst case it's size is N. After that I merging between my approximated sorted array and the buffer. The result is sorted array.

### Testing outputs

- My Time / System Time = 511 / 859 =  **0.5948777648428405**
- My Time / System Time = 417 / 467 =  **0.892933618843683**
- My Time / System Time = 309 / 403 =  **0.7667493796526055**
- My Time / System Time = 308 / 344 =  **0.8953488372093024**
- My Time / System Time = 204 / 483 =  **0.422360248447205**
- My Time / System Time = 204 / 368 =  **0.5543478260869565**
- My Time / System Time = 279 / 291 =  **0.9587628865979382**
- My Time / System Time = 206 / 288 =  **0.7152777777777778**

### Source code of my algorithm

```
    public class StatisticSort {
        private static long minemum;
        private static long sum;

        public static void sort(List<Integer> source) {
            findMinMaxAndSum(source);
            int size = source.size();
            ArrayList<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Vector<Integer> sourceVector = new Vector<Integer>(size);
            sourceVector.setSize(size);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Integer ai = source.get(i);
                int index = calculateIndex(ai, source);

                if (index != i && sourceVector.get(index) == null) {
                    sourceVector.set(index, ai);
                }
                else {
                    buffer.add(ai); // value
                }

            }

            Collections.sort(buffer);
            int bufferSize = buffer.size();
            for (int i = 0, j = 0, counter = 0; i < size || j < bufferSize;) {
                if (i < size && j < bufferSize) {
                    Integer ai = sourceVector.get(i);
                    while (ai == null && i < size) {
                        i++;
                        if (i < size) {
                            ai = sourceVector.get(i);
                        }
                    }
                    if (i == size) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Integer aj = buffer.get(j);
                    if (aj < ai) {
                        source.set(counter, aj);
                        j++;
                    }
                    else {
                        source.set(counter, ai);
                        i++;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                else {
                    if (i < size) {
                        Integer ai = sourceVector.get(i);
                        if (ai != null) {
                            source.set(counter, ai);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if (j < bufferSize) {
                        Integer aj = buffer.get(j);
                        source.set(counter, aj);
                        j++;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static int calculateIndex(Integer ai, List<Integer> source) {
            int size = source.size();
            return Math.min(size - 1, (int) (((ai - minemum) * size * (size - 1)) / (2 * (sum - size * minemum))));
        }

        private static void findMinMaxAndSum(List<Integer> source) {
            long minemum = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            long maximum = -Long.MAX_VALUE;
            long sum = 0;

            for (int value : source) {
                sum += value;
                if (value < minemum) {
                    minemum = value;
                }
                if (value > maximum) {
                    maximum = value;
                }
            }
            StatisticSort.minemum = minemum;
            StatisticSort.sum = sum;
        }
}
```

### Source code of my testing program

```
public abstract class Test {
    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buffer;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public int numberOfTests = 100;
    public int maxValue = 1000;
    public int numberOfItems = 100;

    protected void createBuffer() {
        buffer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            addRandomNumbers(list);
            buffer.add(list);
        }
    }

    protected void createBuffer(int...parametes) {
        buffer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < parametes.length; i++){
            list.add(parametes[i]);
        }
        buffer.add(list);
    }

    protected void addRandomNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            int value = random.nextInt(maxValue);
            list.add(value);
        }
    }

    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cloneBuffer() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> clonedBuffer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++){
            ArrayList<Integer> clonedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = buffer.get(i);
            for(int element : list){
                clonedList.add(element);
            }
            clonedBuffer.add(clonedList);
        }
        return clonedBuffer;
    }

    public abstract void test();
}
```

Performance test

```
public class TestPerformance extends Test{

    private final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void test() {
        createBuffer();

        timer.reset();
        testSystem();
        timeResoult("System");

        timer.reset();
        testMy();
        timeResoult("My List");
    }

    public void test(int numberOfTests) {
        long myTotalTime = 0;
        long systemTotalTime = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++){
            createBuffer();

            timer.reset();
            testSystem();
            long systemTime = timeResoult();
            systemTotalTime += systemTime;

            timer.reset();
            testMy();
            long myTime = timeResoult();
            myTotalTime += myTime;

            System.out.println("My Time / System Time = " + myTime + " / " + systemTime + " = \t" + ((double) myTime / systemTime));
        }
        System.out.println("My Time / System Time = " + ((double) myTotalTime / systemTotalTime));

    }

    private long timeResoult() {
        return timeResoult(null);
    }

    private long timeResoult(String source) {
        long time = timer.check();
        if (source != null) {
            System.out.println(source + ">\tTime: " + time);
        }
        return time;
    }

    private void testMy() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buffer = cloneBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = buffer.get(i);
            StatisticSort.sort(list);
        }
    }

    private void testSystem() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buffer = cloneBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = buffer.get(i);
            Collections.sort(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestPerformance testBasics = new TestPerformance();
    testBasics.numberOfTests = 1000;
    testBasics.numberOfItems = 1000;
    testBasics.maxValue = 1000000;
    testBasics.test(1000);
}
```

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashsort

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You want someone to review your code?  You should probably take this to [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Taking a brief look, probably something you didn't take into consideration is the growth expansion of ArrayList (everytime an item is inserted into an ArrayList or Vector which can't fit into array, all items are copied into new array of twice the size).  For large arrays, this is rather inefficient.  Be sure to set the initial capacity.

Comment: @kdgregory radix have it's own disadvantages. My algorithm got no limitations.

Comment: My point is that you're essentially implementing a radix sort. And when I looked at the related sorts, I saw Flashsort, which is *exactly* what you're implementing.

Comment: Not bad, OP, you're just 16 years behind the bleeding edge! +1

Comment: @Neil it's true for the buffer witch I assume will be small anyway. Vector have fixed size and so the input(its size is not modified).

Comment: BTW the data for which your algo is good should be categorized as *uniformly distributed*, not *random*. That's what your "good linear regression" actually implies.

Comment: @Neil The expansion factor is actually 1.5, and the effect on performance is quite small, almost to the point of being *counterintuitively* small. This is because both memory allocation and array copying are extremely fast, using MMX/SSE vector operations and equivalents on other platforms.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Vector is not fixed size.  It grows like ArrayList, and in fact there should be no reason to have to use Vector here.  The central difference is that Vector operations are always synchronized.

Comment: @kdgregory nice catch! I just finished reading about flash sort, it have the same basic idea of my algorithm how ever he is doing cycles and trying to save extra space. My algorithm use additionally O(N) space witch make it more efficient than flash sort.

Comment: @Neil I think you missed this line: sourceVector.setSize(size);

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Definitely check out `jmh` for serious benchmarking on the JVM. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik We're talking about algorithm and performance.. If we were talking about program design, performance would have relatively little importance.  I think such things should be taken into consideration, as long as we're talking about how best to improve it.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman My comment still holds true for `buffer`.

Comment: @Neil Of course they have to be taken into account, and of course the list shouldn't be resized if it can be avoided. My comment only touches your classification as "rather inefficient". The overhead induced by resizing when doing nothing but inserting the same object is maybe 10-20%.

Comment: @Neil I added size to vector, this does not change the testing performance resolute. I agree with you about the buffer, may be liked list will be better there, how ever I don't think it will change much.

Comment: @Neil Integer-sorting code which uses anything else but `int[]` automatically makes all such microoptimization moot, anyway.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Fundamentally, I don't see why you would implement a *Collection* sort which is specialized to Integers. That doesn't have much utility. You should reimplement as an `int[]` sort and compare with Java's dual-pivot QSort.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik To be fair, coming with a decent algorithm is not easier because it's old. It only betrays lack of research, not lack of creativity.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Java's dual-pivot QSort. I will try that

Comment: @Raphael Exactly, and I fully appreciate OP's work in that capacity. It reminds me of my own youth when I was playing with sort algos in 80286 assembler :)

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman You misunderstood.  You should set the initial capacity of `buffer`, not `sourceVector`

Answer (score 0):

there is one major issue with comparing your sort with `Collections.sort`'s algorithm:

`Collections.sort` is a pure [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) by necessity, all it has is a way to tell which of 2 objects is smaller, all comparison sorts are provably lower bound O(n log n) in the worst case

your sort can't work for arbitrary objects as you need to have an O(1) estimator of where a value will be in the final array

Comment: I don't think this tells the full story since QuickSort is also based on comparison, and it's the algo of choice for all primitive numerics in Java. I am quite convinced that the reason something like OP's idea is not used lies in bad worst cases.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this algoritm also requires a decent linear relation between the values and their place in the result, this is not always common and you pay for that by quicksorting the entire thing anyway.

Comment: This is true, I can't race all the functionality of sort as my algorithm is limited for numbers. So in bounds of my limitations I believe it's a legitimate race. Some times you are working with integer lists and this is what you want to sort.